# When does a Hungry Corpse become a Hungry Torso?

Tags: diablo-iii

When killing a Hungry Corpse, it sometimes spawns a fresh Hungry Torso monster. When does that happen (I want to be prepared), and is there any way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the **remaining damage of the killing blow**.

To be exact the amount for how much is the damage of killing blow higher than the "hungry corpse" remaining life,if that remaining amount is higher than required threshold(specific number unknown for now) the "corpse" will die completely if that amount is lower it will spawn the "torso".

Simply put if the "corpse" is very low on HP and you finish him with strong special ability the chances are it will not spawn the "torso".On the opposite if the "corpse" is hard to kill (depending on your lvl,gear,difficulty...) an you just *autoattack* him expect him to "split".

Comment: Are you positive? Do you have sources or personal experience? Because I've tried to check if this is the case but encountered torsos spawning even when inflicting high amount of damage...

Comment: That is how it looked to me in open beta,I rechecked forums when I posted answer and others had the same impression.Do note that there is much randomness in it since only last hit counts and it depends mostly how much HP is left on monster before last hit,I mean it is harder that it looks to get monster very close to death and then finish him especially when there is a full party.